# Move and rotate line by one point

Tags: fabricjs

I try to reproduce "line" from paint or "Nimbus Screenshot and Screencast", where line changed by 2 points.

Can it possible with standard controls and events or better modified this
jsfiddle.net/ug2gskj1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add some span and line by span's drag events